# Function does not return expected value

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I am not getting back the correct value from function "checkPos" to variable "thesi1. Using CodeBlocks in windows. Any suggestions.

```
int checkPos(int thesi)
{
    switch(thesi)
    {
        case 6:
            thesi = 4;
            break;
        case 3:
            thesi = 8;
            break;
        case 7:
            thesi = 3;
            break;
        case 9:
            thesi = 16;
            break;
        case 14:
            thesi = 10;
            break;

        return thesi;
    }
}


 int main(){ 

    thesi1 = checkPos(newPos);
    cout << "your position is " << thesi1 << endl;
```

Comment: what is the type of thesi1? what is newPos you are passing?

Comment: The code, as shown, will not compile.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve].  Also, please state the result you get and how it differs from the result you expect.

Comment: int main(){
    int thesi1(0),  newPos ;

Comment: int main(){
        int thesi1(0), dice1, newPos ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `return` statement so that it is right after the closing `}` of the `switch` statement. As written, your function has undefined behavior since there is no `return` statement after the `switch` statement. You should turn up the warning level of your compiler to detect such errors.

```
int checkPos(int thesi)
{
    switch(thesi)
    {
        case 6:
            thesi = 4;
            break;
        case 3:
            thesi = 8;
            break;
        case 7:
            thesi = 3;
            break;
        case 9:
            thesi = 16;
            break;
        case 14:
            thesi = 10;
            break;
    }
    return thesi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few  things you missed as well as default case if not in the list values

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int checkPos(int thesi)
{
    switch (thesi)
    {
    case 6:
        thesi = 4;
        break;
    case 3:
        thesi = 8;
        break;
    case 7:
        thesi = 3;
        break;
    case 9:
        thesi = 16;
        break;
    case 14:
        thesi = 10;
        break;
    default:
        cout << thesi<<" Not in the list"<<endl;
        return -1;

    }
    return thesi;
}


int main() {
    int newPos;
    int thesi1 = checkPos(0);
    cout << "your position is " << thesi1 << endl;
}
```

Output

```
0 Not in the list
your position is -1
```